# Scheme/Racket: How does this Honu lang create syntax without evaluation parentheses?

Tags: syntax, scheme, lisp, racket, evaluation

This is the Honu lang created with Racket: https://docs.racket-lang.org/honu/Examples.html?q=hon

The language looks just like other structured langs but it's built on top of Racket which requires parentheses `( )` for evaluation. **How does Honu define statements without parentheses?**

I can define some syntaxes in Racket, but when evaluate them, I need to add the wrapping parentheses:

```
(require syntax/parse/define)
(define-syntax-rule (while Cond Form ...)
  (do [] [(not Cond)] Form ...)
)

(define I 0)
;HOW TO RUN while WITHOUT PARENTHESES?
(while (< I 10)
  (displayln I)
  (set! I (add1 I))
)
```

I can test the Racket code on: https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-racket-online/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honu has `while` already. You can use it like this:

```
#lang honu

var x = 0
while x < 10 {
  printf("~a\n", x);
  x = x + 1;
}
```

The above program prints `0` to `9`.

Honu also provides a way to define your own macros via `define-honu-syntax` in Racket world. Here's an example:

```
;; while.rkt

#lang racket

(provide mywhile)
(require honu-parse
         (for-syntax syntax/parse
                     honu-parse))

(define-honu-syntax mywhile
  (lambda (code)
    (syntax-parse code #:literal-sets (cruft)
      [(_ condition:honu-expression body:honu-body . rest)
       (values
        (racket-syntax (let loop ()
                         (when condition.result
                           body.result
                           (loop))))
        #'rest
        #t)])))
```

```
;; test.honu

#lang honu

require "while.rkt";

var x = 0
mywhile x <= 10 {
  printf("~a\n", x);
  x = x + 1;
}
```

Running `test.honu` should print `0` to `9`, too.

Honu also supports defining macros in Honu world. See an example at https://github.com/racket/honu/blob/master/honu/tests/macros2.honu.

Comment: is it Honu has its own tokenizer? and then Honu converts to s-expressions?

Comment: and, how to use `define-honu-syntax` to create the c++ `Cond ? Form1 : Form2`, because `Cond` here is not an id to put behind `define-honu-syntax`?

Comment: do i have something in Honu like racket:#%app? so i can start form with `Cond` instead of id?

Comment: `(#%app f a)` in Racket would correspond to `f(a)` in Honu, so no, you can't use that trick anymore. Honu doesn't support defining ternary operator, but it does support defining binary operators, so you can define two binary operators that cooperate together to form a ternary operator. Read https://www.cs.utah.edu/~rafkind/papers/honu-2012.pdf for more information about Honu.